# Требуется ли постановка запятой в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

настольный портативный компьютер, выпущенный в сентябре **** года, за шесть лет до компьютера. 
Нужна ли запятая после в сентябре **** года, ведь это же тоже причастный оборот или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Либо уж настольный (стационарный), либо портативный компьютер. Допустим, ваше предложение будет выглядеть так:
**Настольный компьютер, выпущенный в сентябре 1960 года, за шесть лет до портативного компьютера.**
Вторая запятая ставится, так как дальше идет пояснительное предложение: *...в сентябре 1960 года, **то есть** за шесть лет до портативного компьютера.*

> При отсутствии пояснительных союзов **то есть, именно, а именно** и при
>   наличии пояснения выделение происходит обычно с помощью тире, а не
>   запятой. *Разговор шёл один – о погоде; Профессия его была самая мирная
>   – учитель.*

Соответственно предложение может выглядеть так: **Настольный компьютер, выпущенный в сентябре 1960 года — за шесть лет до портативного компьютера.**